# Changing value of nested object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, object

Im having an issue changing the values of keys within an array of objects.  The Object I am working with is quite complicated and each object within the array may have differing numbers of keys within however the bare bones of the JSON looks like:

```
var payload = {
    "data": {
        "form_values": {            
            "70f9": [
                {
                    "form_values": {
                        "6949": "drop"                       
                    },                    
                },
                {                   
                    "form_values": {                        
                        "6949": "drop"                        
                    },
                    
                },
                {                    
                    "form_values": {                        
                        "6949": "drop"                        
                    },
                    
                }
            ],            
        },        
    }
}
```

I have been trying to change the 'drop's to 'active' like such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < payload.data.form_values['70f9'].length; i++ ){
    var payload.data.form_values['70f9'][i].form_values['6949'] = 'active'
}
```

I feel like this normally works but for some reason I'm having issues with it this time

Comment: What "issues"? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Agree w @jered. Looking at the code you have presented, it looks correct, so without more details about the whole script and what exact problems are occurring we can't be more specific

Comment: @jered The error produced is 'var payload.data.form_values['70f9'][i].form_values['6949'] = 'active'
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Module._compile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bad-declaring the variable each time in the loop:

```
 var payload.data.form_values['70f9'][i].form_values['6949'] = 'active'
```

you have to take out that `var`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < payload.data.form_values['70f9'].length; i++ ){
   payload.data.form_values['70f9'][i].form_values['6949'] = 'active'
}
```